# Rendering problems with my first project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

So I am currently working on my first project in android studio, and im following this book on how to create apps but it seems like when I try to run the app to see if its working (Its a blank android app) it prompts me with the Emulator but nothing shows up then I get prompted with this, I've tried googleing error message and there were some solutions but none of them worked for me so I am not sure if I missed something.
What could I be doing wrong?
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUtIB.png)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: also have this problem, just updated everything.

Comment: Try running it on emulator/device and you'll see that those Preview rendering warnings are just that, warnings for the Android Studio preview renderer. They have nothing to do with actual on-device rendering...

Comment: I am currently using the latest version of SDK yes, What exactly did you update? The Android studio software?

Comment: try to rebuild your app and see if this is helping.

Answer (score 1):

The version on the simulator and the preview must be the same:
[api version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DDwN.png)

simply low the level on the preview or install a simulator with a higher level version

Comment: Im pretty sure that both of them are the same version
[Here is a link to the picture](http://i.imgur.com/xY7494X.png?1)
When I try to tick the "Nexus 5 api Working Emulator" it doesnt do anything

Comment: Close the problematic view, go to the Build Menu --> "Clean Project" and when finished, --> "Rebuild Project"

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild your app it usually works for me.